# Unable to skip numbers using a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, iteration

I just want to print some numbers using a basic python for loop:

```
for i in range(10):
    i = i+1
    print(i)
```

*Expected Output :*

```
1
3
5
7
9
```

*Actual Output :*

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Why doesn't the variable 'i' jump one step when it's `i = i+1`. 
What I assume is both `i's` are different? Because I tried printing the id using `print(id(i))`. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: What would your expected output be if the same loop started with eg. `for i in [0,3,-1,12]:` instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thing to note here is that changing the value of `i` does not affect the number of iterations. You current code steps from 0 through 9, incrementing one to the current value. It does *not* skip those iterations. `i` is just a loop variable that the `for` loop assigns, it does not control iteration in any way.

Use the `range` function's `step` parameter instead:

```
In [665]: for i in range(1, 10, 2): # start, stop, step
     ...:     print(i)
     ...: 
1
3
5
7
9
```

What happens is that `range` by default steps one at a time, so you'll end up stepping through iterations you wish to skip.

Comment: The key point to note here is that changing `i` within the loop doesn't have the desired effect as the name `i` will be rebound to the value of the next iteration of the `for` loop each time.

Comment: Code golf: `print(*range(1,10,2),sep="\n")`

Comment: But why isn't i altered when it encounters i = i+1

Comment: @JohnMcIntyreJr. because at the start of each iteration of the forloop - `i` is  set to the next value produced by `range`...

Comment: @John, It does... It is overwritten on the next execution of the interator

Comment: @JohnMcIntyreJr. `i` is just a loop variable. It does not control the iteration in any way.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> p = range(1,10,2)
>>> p
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

or

```
>>> def test(last,step):
...     for item in range(1,last,step)
...         print item
>>> test(10,2)
1 
3
5
7
9
>>> 
>>> test(15,2)
1 
3
5 
7
9
11
13
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try two method, this is in your way,

```
>>> for i in range(10):
...     if i%2!=0:
...       print i
... 
1
3
5
7
9
>>>
```

and the next is, as @colspeed suggested `for i in range(1,10,2)`

Answer (score 1):

Python for loops don't care about any edits made to their temporary variable during the loop. When it reaches the end it ticks whatever iterator you fed it to the next item. i in your case isn't the index of the range you gave it, it's the output of the range, at the loop's inbuilt pointer.
Cricket's answer is the nicest way to solve your problem, but if you wanted to alter the loop from within itself, use external variables:

```
numberlist = range(0,10)
i=0
while i < numberlist[-1]:
    i+=1 #+1 to skip
    print i
    i+=1 #+1 to turn while into for
```

Answer (score 0):

When you iterate over the list `[0,1,...9]` (`range(10)`), at first iteration, `i` is set to `0`, then no matter what you do with `i` from there, it won't change the fact that `i` will be set to `1` at the next iteration, and so on. This is the answer to why it doesn't work as you expect. See other answers for how you can fix it...